PWA. Recent updates to iOS/Android now strip any and all parameters and/or hash from URLs to prevent Cross Site Tracking
I've created a PWA Clock App for work and until recently I could have a single page dynamically load ANY employee clock profile by simply doing the following:

Type their unique link in the browser: https://example.com/clock/?id=1001
Click Share then click Add To Home Screen.
Set a custom name for the icon if I want to.
Click Add.

Done. Awesome web app ready to use.
Then one day... this stopped working on everyone's phone. Meaning...
Forget this:
// https://example.com/clock/?id=1001
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
const employeeId = parseInt(parsedUrl.searchParams.get("id")); // "1001"

And also, forget this:
// https://example.com/clock/#1001
// https://example.com/clock#1001
const employeeId = parseInt(window.location.hash.slice(1)); // "1001"

After hours of frustration I've decided to do the dumbest thing I could think of which is to create a physical directory for an employee using the same employee id just to say I've tried everything I could think of and what do you know... It worked.
Now I have to use this:
// https://example.com/clock/1001
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
const pathParts = parsedUrl.pathname.split('/');
const employeeId = parseInt(pathParts[pathParts.length - 1]); // "1001"

Please "...say it ain't so. This joke is a heart breaker."

this of course can be fixed with the right server code, where you don't need to create a physical directory - but you've told us nothing about your server, so the answer is a pineapple

Good point. I'm using Deno as a server with NGINX on the edge.

that doesn't really add much info, except that if you're using Deno, then you can do what you need without creating actual directories for each employee - still not enough info though to help you - I'd use express package

Well, it looks like I had created routes that either return a file or a directory. This has got to be the problem... I'll take a a look.
